# First Tab indents 4 spaces in VS Code, then 2. All settings are 2 spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

All my settings are set to 2 spaces when indenting. However, on a new line, the first indentation using Tab indents the code by 4, and every subsequent Tab indents by 2.

Comment: Just as a test, does disabling the setting `Editor: Detect Indentation` make any difference?

Comment: I have the same issue! disabling `Editor: Detect Indentation` doesn't help